# Enable zooming in a uiscrollview with paging enabled and scrolling enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a uiscrollview that i load with an array of images in order that i can scroll through the pictures with an effect similar to the photos effect in the IOS. I am using this code:

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics"];
    fileExists   = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageFilePath];
    if(fileExists){

        imgs=[[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];


    [imgs addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics/pic1.png"]]];
    [imgs addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics/pic2.png"]]];
    [imgs addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics/pic3.png"]]];
    [imgs addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics/pic4.png"]]];


    CGSize imageSize;
    imageSize.height = 648;
    imageSize.width = 927;
    self.scroll1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height);

    self.scroll1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * imgs.count, imageSize.height );
    self.scroll1.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    self.scroll1.maximumZoomScale=3.0;
    self.scroll1.pagingEnabled = YES;


    self.scroll1.delegate=self;

    CGFloat xPos = 0.0;

    for (UIImage *image in imgs) {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        [self.scroll1 addSubview:imageView];
        xPos += imageSize.width;

    }


    }

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int positionScrollPrim = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

    int positionScroll = positionScrollPrim / 927 ;

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imgs objectAtIndex:positionScroll]];
    //UIImage *tmep =  [imgs objectAtIndex:1];

    return imageView;
}
```

I can't achieve the right result, instead i get a bunch of weird behaviors such as incorrect zooming and no more scrolling when i try to zoom. I guess that my problem is in the viewForZoomingInScrollView section, that's why i tried to solve it using the above code. But i just can't make it work. What am i missing?

Comment: you shouldn't return a new instance in viewForZoomingInScrollView, you should return existing subview from your scrollView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common approach is to use two scroll views: The outer one scrolls through the images and each image is wrapped in another scroll view which is responsible for zooming.

Comment: can you please provide a code snippet just to know how to handle it ?\

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work...either i got lost or it won't work can you please help out?

Comment: There are already several libraries like [AGPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/andreagiavatto/AGPhotoBrowser/tree/master/src) or [CXPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/ChrisXu1221/CXPhotoBrowser/tree/master/CXPhotoBrowser) and [examples on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970665/zooming-within-nested-uiscrollviews) which will help you understand the approach.